# How to invoke a new notepad with Java and save it in a directory in windows?

Tags: java

I am currently logging test execution results in to a textfile(An existing one.) How do I create a textfile with a timestamp and save it in a windows directory? The code I am using currently is

```
    File outputResultFile = new File(CompleteFileNameForNotepad);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputResultFile));
    String str = "text to write in to the file";
    outputFile.println(str);
    outputFile.close();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you talking about a new .txt document or the Notepad application?

Comment: You could use new Date().toString() or System.currentTimeMilis(), or maybe would be good see an example

Comment: @edem - I mean a new .txt document.

Comment: @QVSJ: then state that in your question. Consider editing it and removing all the nonsense about NotePad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I thought the name of the application in windows is 'Notepad'. Btw do you have some answers other than a sense of right and wrong..? Thanks.

Comment: @QVSJ: NotePad is a an application for viewing text files and has nothing to do with your need. What you are trying to do is to save your data into a text file. How you view it later is completely independent of your problem. And sure I have plenty of answers (sometimes even correct answers), but the right answer has already been given below. Just use logging.

Comment: Just edited the question. to include 'Textfile'. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss").format(new Date()) + ".txt";
File outputResultFile = new File(fileName);
...
```

Note: what you call a notepad is more commonly called a "file".

Comment: 10+, especially for your last line!

Comment: maybe would be better forget `:` in win OS

Comment: @Spaeth: Yeah I edited the answer to replace them with dashes.

Comment: I am selecting this over logger since I am executing multithreaded code and need execution results for each thread in a different 'textfile'( I shall be careful next time:-) ) in a specific format. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a logging framework instead. Check out [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for example. You can then alter the logging format and which classes are logged by tweaking the logging configuration. This means you don't have to alter your code.

The log4j.properties below would log all classes under the package foo, at WARN level or higher to the Console, using the pattern "2000-09-07 14:07:41,508 [main] INFO  MyApp - Entering application."

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

To log to a file use a different Appender, such as org.apache.log4j.FileAppender or org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender. For your purpose org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender would be suitable.